How to specify a default based on the request for a field in the create form of a TabularInline
I have a model which has a language_code field:
class SkillSynonym(StandardModel):
    """SkillSynonym class"""

    skill = models.ForeignKey(
        Skill, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="synonyms"
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    language_code = models.CharField(
        db_index=True,
        max_length=8,
        verbose_name="Language",
        choices=settings.LANGUAGES,
        default=settings.LANGUAGE_CODE,
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("name", "language_code")

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        """SkillSynonym object representation."""
        return f"{self.name}"

This is then edited through a TabularInline admin inside the SkillAdmin:
class SkillSynonymInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SkillSynonym
    extra = 0

    def get_queryset(self, request: HttpRequest):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)

        language_code = request.GET.get("language", "en")
        if language_code:
            queryset = queryset.filter(language_code=language_code)

        return queryset

As you can see I am already filtering the records to be shown in the inline field by the language GET parameter. This is set by the parler extension in the parent admin.
I would also like to set a default value for language_code in the create form for the TabularInline
I've tried overriding get_formset, but I'm not sure what to do with it.
